# How does Python networking work?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, host

I'm a total beginner and newb at all this programming stuff and I'm trying to learn as best as I can but I'm having issues. Can anyone explain Python networking? Where I'm getting confused is my book says:

> "You can run several clients while the server is still running. By replacing the call to gethostname in the client with the **actual host name of the machine where the server is running**, you can have the two programs connect across a network from one machine to another."

I'm having trouble understanding the part with the asterisks surrounding it. I don't know what they mean by that.

```
#Client Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1234

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)



#Server code:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1234
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
```

Here's the code that my book has but I don't really understand it.

Comment: You should post the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably there's some line of code along the lines of:

```
socket.create_connection(socket.gethostname())
```

And they want you to either specify the ip address, something like:

```
socket.create_connection("192.168.1.1")
```

Or specify the hostname, something like:

```
socket.create_connection("my_hostname")
```

Comment: Does the "my_hostname" need to be a specific name or can you name it whatever you want?

Comment: "my_hostname" needs to be the hostname of the computer you want to connect to. For instance if you did "ping my_hostname" then if "my_hostname" were valid ping would be able to turn "my_hostname" into an IP, otherwise it would say "ping: unknown host my_hostname".